# How can I improve the accuracy of OpenCV checkerboard detection in this case?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv

I would like to track the location of checkerboard corners in this stereo fisheye camera, using OpenCV in Python.

[image: Stereo fisheye checkerboard]

To help the algorithm, I am only running the checkerboard detection on the parts of the image where I know the checkerboard is. Here is the code I use for one side of the image. Similar code is used for the other checkerboard on the right.

```py
    # Extract the left checkerboard 
    img_L = img[box_L[0][1]:box_L[1][1], box_L[0][0]:box_L[1][0]]

    # Detect corners
    ret_L, corners_L = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img_L, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)

    if ret_L:
        # Improve accuracy
        corners_L = cv2.cornerSubPix(img_L, corners_L, (5,5),(-1,-1), criteria)
        # Draw the vertices
        img_L = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img_L, CHECKERBOARD, corners_L, ret_L)
        # And draw it back into the main image
        InsertImage(img, img_L, box_L[0])
```

[image: Stereo fisheye checkerboard with detection markers]

As you can see, the quality of the image isn't great, and the detector has some difficulty making a good detection. The checkerboards won't move very far, but I do need to know their location and shape accurately for calibration.

About a third of the time, the left half doesn't detect a checkerboard at all (as you can see in this image), and the vertices jitter about quite a bit.

There's not a lot I can do to improve the image quality due to the physical nature of my setup and these cameras.

**Questions:**

1. What can I do to improve the checkerboard detection?
2. Is there a better checkerboard detector available in OpenCV?

As far as I understand, the checkerboard detector is only detecting the corners using a saddle detector. Perhaps there's some kind of algorithm which can use the intersections of the long straight edges to help improve accuracy? For example, is there a function to help fit Bézier curves to the lines of the checkerboard, then I can do intersections to get the vertices? Here is an illustration I made using a paint program:

[image: Checkerboard intersections]

Comment: Considering about accuracy, you will need some method to evaluate accuracy.
e.g. the example you showed with paint looks plausible, but how accurate? How do you know if this is the best?
In other words, if someone provide some new method, you need to compare the existing and the new method.
Without the definition of accuracy, no one can say "This way is more accurate".

Comment: I found the function `findChessboardCornersSB` in OpenCV's manual. (But I don't know the difference between findChessboardCorners and this, so I don't know if this will help.)  

Both seem to require enough white space around the pattern for robustness. This may be contributing to the detection failing?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would try to implement the lines to points approach likes you described.
(Because, it's probably half a day or a day's work at most.)

For example...

- Erosion(Morphological transformation) will help to detect the pattern region.
  Pattern will becomes one large black region with many white holes.
- If your chess pattern is rectangular, e.g. `minAreaRect` for the detected region will provide very coarse pattern line direction.
  This is coarse, but will enough to divide the pattern's edges to 2 groups.
- Fit some curve to the each long edge line, or fit straight line localy.
  And then, decide the corner positions from them.

However, as already mentioned (as comment for question), it is necessary to prepare some accuracy evaluation method first, I think.

Comment: Yes, this is just an idea, so someone will say "this is not the answer".
Or may be evaluated as "Significantly Complicated" because this is not existing function name.

Comment: Thanks for this. You make a good point about evaluating the accuracy. I'm not sure how I'd go about that, however, I think for now that if the points look stable, and they visually seem to track the movement of the checkerboard, then it's probably better than what I have now.

Comment: I don't know if this is a good evaluation way... Preparing pattern image by simulation will become one way, I think.
We know "true corner position" because images created by simulation. So, we will be able to blur or deform the simulated images, and confirm the detector's result.

Comment: I've implemented it and it looks pretty good. Very stable at least, and visually I can see that the tracking looks accurate when moving the checkerboard a little bit. I'll write it up when I get a chance.